# ProblemDetails not working when returning TypedResults.BadRequest<string>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-8.0, minimal-apis, asp.net-core-8

I have this sample of an ASP.NET Core 8 application using ProblemDetails.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseExceptionHandler();
app.UseStatusCodePages();

app.MapGet("/400", () => TypedResults.BadRequest());
app.MapGet("/exception", () =>
{
    throw new Exception("Exception!");
});

app.MapGet("/400/hello", () => TypedResults.BadRequest("Hello"));

app.Run();
```

The first two endpoints where I throw an exception or return a `TypedResult.BadRequest` I get a nice JSON formatted error response, like this:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400
}
```

However, with the third endpoint which returns a `TypedResult.BadRequest<string>`, I only get the string back, no JSON object. How come? I'd like to get a problem details object with the message as a `details` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because `TypedResult.BadRequest<TValue>` accepts parameter of `TValue? error` which as [the docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.typedresults.badrequest?view=aspnetcore-8.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-typedresults-badrequest-1(-0)):

> `TValue`
> The type of error object that will be JSON serialized to the response body.

> `error` `TValue`
> The value to be included in the HTTP response body.

So it does exactly what it claims to - serializes the provided value as JSON response body, hence the `hello` you see as the response. If you try something like:

```
TypedResults.BadRequest(new {error = 1}
```

Then you will get accordingly:

```
{"error":1}
```

Also you can try using [`TypedResults.Problem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.typedresults.problem?view=aspnetcore-8.0) (check out parameters you can pass to it):

```cs
app.MapGet("/400/hello2", () => TypedResults.Problem("hello", statusCode: 400));
```

Which produces the following JSON body:

```json
{
   "type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
   "title":"Bad Request",
   "status":400,
   "detail":"hello"
}
```